# ethminer || Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: cpp-ethereum, segfault, ethminer

I recently updated cpp-ethereum. I am now on ethminer version 1.2.3

when I start it to mine with `ethminer --opencl-device 1` I get the folowing output.

```
Getting work package...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What might be wrong. before the cpp-ethereum update it worked.

Comment: maybe try `gdb --args ethminer --opencl-device 1` to see if you can backtrace the error

Comment: `-bash: gdb: command not found` what is gdb?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ , you can install it with `sudo aptitude install gdb`. once in gdb you enter run, when it crashes you type backtrace. maybe this would be more appropriate to post in the reposiory though if it crashes all the time ;)

Comment: does it work on osx?

Comment: sorry can't comment on this, this was a linux thing

Comment: how did you upgrade ethminer? downloading the executables or building from source? what version operating system are you running?

Comment: I am on OSX Yosemite, i update via `brew install cpp-ethereum` which was kind of a pain because boost got stuck during installation and I had to install boost first: `brew install boost boost-python `

Comment: you could try the disk image download from https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases and see if it crashes as well. or just use an older version downloaded from the same page.

Comment: If you have lldb on your system then you can use that to run ethminer. Many of the commands it supports are identical in behaviour to gdb. You should use this to run the program, then when it segfaults you can generate a backtrace. If this is beyond your capabilities then I recommend submitting a bug report on the repository on github.

Comment: Bob from the C++ team here. Yes, please can you install gdb, and run through gdb so we can get some clue about what the issue is? Please could you also log an issue on Github, so we can track the work for this, which will likely have some back-and-forth? Thanks! http://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok never mind, think I had the same issue described in issue #477 https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/477#issuecomment-206313939

Resolved it by downloading https://build.ethdev.com/cpp-binaries-data/release-1.2.3/Ethereum.dmg
and copying the described file: libjsoncpp.dylib from `AlethOne/Contents/Frameworks/libjsoncpp.dylib`
to
`usr/local/lib/`

now it works.