# ethminer -G Segmentation Fault

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethminer, segfault

I'm having a very weird issue... My rig has 3 RX 480 and it seems unstable as soon as I install the driver. I've tested all OS (windows 8 32 bits, 8.1 64 bits, Windows 10, Ubuntu server) and I'm now on an Ubuntu Desktop LTS 16.04.

I managed to install the AMD drivers but lost the X11 interface so I'm connected using SSH.

As I'm a big noob I've struggled for days to get ethminer installed and it's now setup from apt-get (couldn't get the git version to work).

ethminer runs well (but no hashrate) but when I type -G I have the following error:

```
~/Downloads/cpp-ethereum/build$ ethminer -G
Segmentation fault
```

But when typing ethminer -F $URL I have the following issue:

```
miner  10:47:27.154|ethminer  Getting work package...
  ✘  10:47:27.307|ethminer  Failed to submit hashrate.
  ✘  10:47:27.307|ethminer  Dynamic exception type: jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 52

JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...
```

I'm totally stuck and have exhausted all my options, can you please help? Just for information, I don't have the blockchain locally as I'm trying to mine from a pool.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: This is an issue, but I feel this question is in a wrong place. Bug reports should go to the issue tracker of related products.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report

Comment: Thanks but I really think it's a problem on my side not on the dev side as the issue might be coming from my graphic card setup or some missing package / conf file.

Comment: No please don't close... I really need the help of the community :(

Comment: A segmentation fault is a crash - it's an issue if the program does not gracefully shut down or give an error message. The project should have procedures in place how to report such issues and get more information from you and then proceed to help and fix this issue.

Comment: Please report it here https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/issues

Comment: Ok I understand, can you at least help me as where I should post that issue?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/117/87 -- Fabien: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/7931/87 or http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2667/87 ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you built the source yourself, I recommend rebuilding with debugging symbols and then using gdb to capture detailed crash info.  Submit that info as a bug report to cpp-ethereum and they will eventually fix it.

In the interim, an easier thing to do is probably to download a pre-compiled version and see if it still has problems.  If it does, then your hardware/drivers/etc are probably at fault.  If the pre-compiled stuff works then there may be something wrong with your build environment.